# How to build Xcode 4.2 + ios5.0 beta application in in Xcode 4.0.2 or Xcode 3.2.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i have installed new Xcode 4.2 with ios 5.0 beta . Now I have open my old applications and change targate to Latest 5.0 build for simulator.
Now when I try to run this project in Xcode 3.2.5 in other Mac is crash in starting all time.

I think this is because of Architectures Armv7.

Is there any way that I can Make application which run in all versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target 5.0 from anything before XCode 4.2. You need to change it to target a version that XCode 3.2.5 recognizes, like 4.0 or 4.3.2.

Comment: I have made that Changes but this will cause App crash when i change targate to 5.0 to 4.2. it works fine when i choose targate to 5.0

Comment: the crash log is -[UIImage initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c49210
2011-08-20 11:01:54.343 NewTwitter[727:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c49210'

Comment: No its my old app which i have made in Xcode 4.0.2 and "NewTwitter" is my app name